# How to remove 'current' widget so that def can be used as a Global Variable

Tags: python, pyqt5, widget, qdialog

Using PyQt5 I would like to create a global definition that I can use for pushbuttons on multiple widgets.

For example I have the below code within a class,

```
        self.menupb.clicked.connect(self.gotomenu)

    def gotomenu(self):
        widget.addWidget(menu)
        widget.removeWidget(formpage)
```

This will simply remove the Form Page QDialog I am currently on and take me back to the Menu Page QDialog.

However - I have multiple QDialog's with this same pushbutton, so I am wondering how I can make the 'gotomenu' definition Global so that it would close the current Qdialog rather than have to specify which widget to close.

This would allow me to use the same definition globally rather than have to add it locally to every class.

I hope this makes sense and the answer is not too obvious - I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I'm under the impression that you're using a QStackedWidget, you're trying to add the same button to navigate between pages and you're also adding QDialog as pages to the stacked widget. And if that's true, you're probably following a YouTube tutorial (from a certain Hala) that is known for providing **a lot** of terrible suggestions. Is this the case?

Comment: No I am not following a tutorial, however I am fairly new to python and I am managing to stumble along by just using the w3schools tutorial etc. - I am trying to avoid using the currentIndex +1 technique if that is what you are refering to so that I dont have a buildup of QDialogs over time

Comment: There's little point in continuously adding and removing widgets from QStackedWidget, as you should just switch to them when required. It's also wrong to use QDialog inside QStackedWidget, and you should use QWidget instead. If you want to provide a more comprehensive navigation, possibly with common buttons, then either use the QStackedWidget within the layout of the top level window and add the button(s) to that layout. Using a "global" button that is continuously placed here and there is discouraged. Alternatively, look into the QWizard API. If you want further help, please provide a [mre].